# When do I use HttpServer Utility.HtmlEncode MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have recently have been reading a lot regarding using ASP.NET MVC5. One thing that I am not sure of is one of the books I read states that you should use HttpServerUtility. HtmlEncode in your views in order to prevent XSS attacks, however I then read something that said view items automatically use this unless you use the http raw method. When is it prudent to use HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode in your views and how can you tell when it is needed and when it is not without having to test every piece of input for XSS injection?

Comment: Here's a good article regarding XSS and CSRF vulnerabilities and how to protect against them https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708755.aspx  for security on the web in general always keep up to date with Troy Hunts blog http://www.troyhunt.com/

Answer (score 2):

You're some-what accurate. Properties on your Model that *do not* implement `IHtmlString` will be encoded by default (therefore preventing most XSS attacks). If they do implement that interface, they will be output as-is (as the interface assumes you are generating some form of markup).

To answer the primary question, "when is it prudent": When you are outputting user input to your page. If you have a custom helper written to deliver an `IHtmlString`, it's advisable within that method to encode it (as part of the final output). This holds true for any kind of data that may be output to the page and was originally generated (or modified thereafter) by a user.